# 5ghz WIFI network offline since adding 2.4ghz network on Nokia router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

My Nokia WIFI router (Nokia WIFI Beacon 2) used to broadcast double band (2.4ghz and 5ghz) under the same name. I added a 2.4ghz network in order to connect a robot vacuum (it only takes 2.4ghz...) and since then, 5ghz network is offline.

Also, since then, my WIFI speed tops between 70 and 95mb/s (vs. 160 before adding the 2.4ghz network for the robot to connect, and vs current ethernet speed).

Is this some sort of known problems? How can I have a 2.4ghz network for my vacuum, and a 5ghz network for the rest of my devices?

Here are pictures for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try forgetting the network.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't appear (I guess since it is shown as "offline" in the admin page of the router)

Comment: Have you powerecycled the router? Checked for and installed updated firmware? Reset the router and reconfigured it? If the router is behaving differently than it did before, those are common steps to perform in troubleshooting such issues.

Comment: I did, nothing changes :(